# Obtener los datos de una tabla Pivot laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Estoy intentando obtener los datos de mi tabla pivot.

Ahorita de la forma como lo hago es así

```html
 $sala = Saluser::where('sala_id',$sala->id)->pluck('user_id');


$usuario = User::whereIn('id',$sala)->get();
```

el inconveniente es que debo de hacer dos consultas, lo cual en una relación. uno a muchos, simplemente aplicando el With me carga los datos relacionados. Con eloquent.

pero está vez es de muchos a muchos

lo cual

Tengo

```html
|Users|
|-----|
|ID   |
|Name |
|etc  |
-------

|Salusers|
|--------|
|Id      |
|user_id |
|sala_id |
|--------|



|Salas |
|------|
|id    |
|titulo|
|descri|
|etc   |
|------|
```

Mis relaciones las tengo de este modo: desde el modelo usuario

```html
 public function Salas() {

return $this->belongsToMany(Sala::class,'salusers');
 
}
```

desdee el modelo Sala

```html
public function Salas(){

return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'salusers');
}
```

desde el  pivot.

```html
public function User(){
   
return $this->belongstoMany(User::class,'user_id');
    
}



 public function Sala(){

return $this->belongstoMany(Sala::class,'sala_id');

 }
```

-
**En resumen**

Estoy enviando el Id de la sala:

Y necesito obtener

toda la información de una sala

con todos los usuarios que están inscritos a el.

Answer (score 0):

¿Por qué no haces uso simplemente de la relación?

**EnAlgunControlador.php**

```php
public function miFuncion(Request $request)
{
    // id de sala
    $id_sala = $request->get('id');
    // instancia sala
    $sala = Sala::with('users')->find($id_sala);

    return $sala;
}
```

Con esto ya tienes a los usuarios

```php
echo $sala->users;
```

---

Lo que no entiendo es tu modelo intermedio, estás usando un modelo personalizado para el Pivot? Si es así hazlo que extienda la clase `Pivot` en lugar de model y cuando definas las relaciones en `User` y `Sala` defínelas del siguiente modo:

**Sala.php**

```php
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')
        ->using('App\Salauser');
}
```

PD: En este modelo intermedio no es necesario definir las relaciones con los otros modelos.